# Unable to edit content in Accordion app: Bad Request

Tags: 2sxc

On the page I have an app accordion with a content app inside.
For a few days I have not been able to edit the content when I add the module to new pages.
On the pages where the module has been present for some time I can do it.

When I click on the "edit" icon [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5g1au.jpg) this message appears. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqTLq.jpg)

I also attach message from the log

> AbsoluteURL /api/2sxc/cms/block/template DefaultDataProvider DotNetNuke.Da
> AbsoluteURL:/api/2sxc/cms/block/template
> DefaultDataProvider:DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke
> ExceptionGUID:6c9efb0c-78ff-4599-af61-6b973e82ea06
> AssemblyVersion:
> PortalId:-1
> UserId:-1
> TabId:-1
> RawUrl:
> Referrer:
> UserAgent:
> ExceptionHash:rObY+Ux5mICpJlywUl8wnSzVnNE=
> Message:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> StackTrace:
> at ToSic.Eav.Apps.Parts.EntitiesManager.UpdateParts(IEntity orig, Dictionary`2 values, Nullable`1 draft) in C:\Projects\2sxc\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.Apps\Parts\Entity\EntitiesManager_Update.cs:line 42
> at ToSic.Eav.Apps.Parts.EntitiesManager.UpdateParts(Int32 id, Dictionary`2 values, Nullable`1 draft) in C:\Projects\2sxc\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.Apps\Parts\Entity\EntitiesManager_Update.cs:line 18
> at ToSic.Sxc.Blocks.Edit.BlockEditorForEntity.Update(Dictionary`2 newValues) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Sxc\ToSic.Sxc\Blocks\Edit\BlockEditorForEntity.cs:line 57 at ToSic.Sxc.Blocks.Edit.BlockEditorForEntity.EnsureLinkToContentGroup(Guid cgGuid) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Sxc\ToSic.Sxc\Blocks\Edit\BlockEditorForEntity.cs:line 39 at ToSic.Sxc.Blocks.Edit.BlockEditorBase.SaveTemplateId(Int32 templateId, Boolean forceCreateContentGroup) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Sxc\ToSic.Sxc\Blocks\Edit\BlockEditorBase.cs:line 64 at ToSic.Sxc.WebApi.InPage.AppViewPickerBackend.SaveTemplateId(Int32 templateId, Boolean forceCreateContentGroup) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Sxc\ToSic.Sxc.WebApi\InPage\AppViewPickerBackend.cs:line 22 at ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.WebApi.Cms.BlockController.Template(Int32 templateId, Boolean forceCreateContentGroup) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.WebApi\Dnn\WebApi\Cms\BlockController.cs:line 127 at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] ) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.d__18`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__18`1.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()
> InnerMessage:
> InnerStackTrace:
> Source:ToSic.Eav.Apps

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you provide more details about your steps, what do you mean by, "when I add the module to new pages." Are you adding a New Module? Or adding a copy of an Existing Module? Have you modified the View? What version of Dnn and 2sxc are you running? Have you gone in to the apps Admin/Data and tried to directly edit the record?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help.
It happens when I add a new form to the page (no copy).
The DNN version is 9.1 and the 2sxc version is 11.10.1.
I'm not using modified views: is an "accordion" app with a "content" app with a "text only" template inside.

Thank you

Comment: NOTE; If I insert the "content" app with the "text only" content I can modify the content, the problem occurs when this is inside an "accordion" app even if the contents inserted long ago in the old pages are still editable.

Comment: Hi Marco - the first step in such a scenario is to update 2sxc to the latest LTS (11.22). Please write if it fixed your issue.